# Change entire content of console to reverse video

Tags: c, linux, console-application, ncurses

I have written a small pager in C using ncurses on Linux. Because this pager is only for myself, and because I find it easier to read text with the whole page in reverse video, I want to find a way to change the entire screen colour to reverse video, i.e. not just until the last character before the newline. Something like the difference between the commands `emacs` and `emacs -r`.

Comment: You could also consider changing the colour settings of your terminal emulator to use black on white if you like it better.

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't use X, I use the tty/console.

Comment: What operating system? On Linux you  can [change the colours](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147462/how-can-i-change-the-tty-colors) for the virtual terminal as you like.

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes it's on Linux, I edited the post to make that more clear.

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, I have looked at them, but those don't do much better than `attron()`. They change the text colour _up to the newline_ and not to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @user3121023 Yes. It doesn't appear to work (at least over SSH). I also used `use_default_colors()` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gave me black text on a white background.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    if (has_colors()) {
        assume_default_colors( COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);
        start_color();
    }
    printw("line 1\n");
    printw("line 2\n");
    printw("line 3\n");
    printw("press enter");
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, on my old version, I put `start_color()` _before_ `assume_default_colors()`... how silly of me.